Grub2 not booting initrd
I have a laptop (with UEFI) that used to be able to boot from a usb stick, but can't any more. The problem started when I interrupted a fresh install of Devuan Live. The laptop has a non-removable mmcblk device and a removable (real) hard disk. Both have several linux kernels on them (Debian, Ubuntu). At power on I get the usual grub2 menu, but whatever I choose: it loads the kernel, then the initrd, but then nothing else happens. If I just load a kernel (no initrd) and boot, it starts booting but halts with a kernel panic (VFS syncing problem). memtest won't boot either.
What could be the source of problem, and is there anything I could do to save the laptop? The only tool I have on the laptop itself is the grub2 console. Otherwise I could move the hard disk to another PC, put something on it, put it back in the laptop and try to get it booted.

Do you get the other hard disk listed within grub console and  typing ls ?

Grub will boot from last install. But if you have the other installs, can you boot from them? Does ls show drives & partitions? Then drill down to find installs. ls (hd0,1)/ and then boot & grub. Then you may be able to boot with configfile (hdX,Y)/boot/grub/grub.cfg where X, Y is drive & partition with a /boot/grub/grub.cfg file.

A Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on ... means the kernel is not able to find a root filesystem.
If the text at the ... is unknown-block(0,0), then either the root filesystem is specified by UUID or the kernel cannot find a driver corresponding to the specified root device name.
